# How to avoid for picking up already existing Database Node --Recyclerview Items

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

The issue i am facing is while updating user message details like whether user has seen the message or not ,firebase creating nodes with previous message Ids and causing to create empty text in Chat App.

My Chat Workflow process is:

--While Sending a message to another User using Groupie Recyclerview i created a separate reference with Parent Node as "Messages". It looks like this

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Messages/$fromId/$toId")
val toRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Messages/$toId/$fromId")
```

fromId -- Current User 
toId   -- Sending message to another recipient

While Sending messages there is another function which will pickup for listening messages from both end by identifying ChatFromItem Adapter and ChatToItem Adapter.

in ChatTo Adapter, i wrote logic to pickup seen status

```
  toRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

        for (ds in p0.children) {

            val fromuserupdate = HashMap<String,String>()

            if (chatMessage.fromId != FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid && chatMessage.toId == FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid){


                val Totoken = ds.child("tokey").value.toString()

                val Frommessageid = ds.child("fromkey").value.toString()


                val toUserChatRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users-messages").child(fromId).child(toId).child(Totoken)

                val fromUserref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users-messages").child(toId).child(fromId).child(Frommessageid)

                                                    fromuserupdate.put("messageseen","true")

                fromUserref.updateChildren(fromuserupdate as Map<String,Any>).addOnCompleteListener { }
                toUserChatRef.updateChildren(fromuserupdate as Map<String,Any>).addOnCompleteListener { }

                ChatFromItem

                fromUserref.removeEventListener(this)
                toUserChatRef.removeEventListener(this)


            }

        } })
```

When trying to send new message to other which its first time, i can update Seen status without issues but when i try to send another message the logic pickups old message database path and creates another node which causes any empty value in chat application and again when i go to any activity and return to ChatActivity it creates addition Node with Null .

Here i am using message seen as String not boolean.

My Database output

```
"users-messages" : {
"4bgqdomQZlRIFnq9lHtKE78wyrv2" : {
  "f4b3phpVJnTByNt2vgCKnKRuxc82" : {
    "-M7nbxCZ3WwPGFcLRMGx" : {
      "messageseen" : "true"
    },
    "-M7nbxCakllN4LvLsOQ0" : {
      "fromId" : "f4b3phpVJnTByNt2vgCKnKRuxc82",
      "fromkey" : "-M7nbxCZ3WwPGFcLRMGx",
      "fulldate" : "21/05/2020",
      "message" : "hi",
      "messageseen" : "true",
      "timespot" : " 01:16 AM",
      "timestamp" : 1590003971,
      "toId" : "4bgqdomQZlRIFnq9lHtKE78wyrv2",
      "tokey" : "-M7nbxCakllN4LvLsOQ0"
    },
    "-M7neJ-qsFODYXbaZeHS" : {
      "fromId" : "4bgqdomQZlRIFnq9lHtKE78wyrv2",
      "fromkey" : "-M7neJ-qsFODYXbaZeHS",
      "fulldate" : "21/05/2020",
      "message" : "hello",
      "messageseen" : "true",
      "timespot" : " 01:26 AM",
      "timestamp" : 1590004589,
      "toId" : "f4b3phpVJnTByNt2vgCKnKRuxc82",
      "tokey" : "-M7neJ-qsFODYXbaZeHT"
    }
  }
},
"f4b3phpVJnTByNt2vgCKnKRuxc82" : {
  "4bgqdomQZlRIFnq9lHtKE78wyrv2" : {
    "-M7nbxCZ3WwPGFcLRMGx" : {
      "fromId" : "f4b3phpVJnTByNt2vgCKnKRuxc82",
      "fromkey" : "-M7nbxCZ3WwPGFcLRMGx",
      "fulldate" : "21/05/2020",
      "message" : "hi",
      "messageseen" : "true",
      "timespot" : " 01:16 AM",
      "timestamp" : 1590003971,
      "toId" : "4bgqdomQZlRIFnq9lHtKE78wyrv2",
      "tokey" : "-M7nbxCakllN4LvLsOQ0"
    },
    "-M7nbxCakllN4LvLsOQ0" : {
      "messageseen" : "true"
    },
    "-M7neJ-qsFODYXbaZeHT" : {
      "fromId" : "4bgqdomQZlRIFnq9lHtKE78wyrv2",
      "fromkey" : "-M7neJ-qsFODYXbaZeHS",
      "fulldate" : "21/05/2020",
      "message" : "hello",
      "messageseen" : "true",
      "timespot" : " 01:26 AM",
      "timestamp" : 1590004589,
      "toId" : "f4b3phpVJnTByNt2vgCKnKRuxc82",
      "tokey" : "-M7neJ-qsFODYXbaZeHT"
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

How to avoid creating additional nodes by not touching old values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get more granular information about the data that was modified in the database in your code. In that case you'll be better off using a `ChildEventListener` instead of a `ValueEventListener`.

With `ChildEventListener` you get called for each child that was added, updated, removed or moved, and you can then easily update the UI based on that. For example, if you only want to add new nodes from the database to your list, you'd do something like:

```
toRef.addChildEventListener(object :ChildEventListener{
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildKey: String) {

        val fromuserupdate = HashMap<String,String>()

        if (chatMessage.fromId != FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid && chatMessage.toId == FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid){

            val Totoken = snapshot.child("tokey").value.toString()
            val Frommessageid = snapshot.child("fromkey").value.toString()

            ...

        } 
    })
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. All these days i was testing ValueEventListener inside ChildEventListener , due to which old values are picking up not the new ones. When i applied your way , i am getting i am expecting results.